# Intelligent __init__.py

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have written a general purpose package called `global_imports` which I use in many of my applications.
Within `global_imports` I also include a `params_<app name>.py` file for each application, inside it contains constants which I use specific to each application.
This package is placed as a submodule within each of my applications; i.e. `<app name>.global_imports`

Within `global_imports.__init__` I have the following code block

```
mainrepo = globals()['__name__']

if mainrepo == 'a.global_imports':
    from .params_a import *
elif mainrepo == 'b.global_imports':
    from .params_b import *
```

This allows my applications to retrieve their necessary constants from `global_imports`.
But this only works if my applications are isolated.

There is a submodule in application `a` called `filereader` which requires the defined constants in `global_imports.params_a`. This submodule `a.filereader` is cloned into application `b` as `b.filereader`.

Now because `globals()['__name__']` only returns the name of the `global_imports` package within the package it resides in. If I were to run `b.filereader`, it would not import`global_imports.params_a` as required by `b.filereader`, but instead import `global_imports.params_b`

Is there a method to retrieve the name of the package that is importing `global_imports`?
i.e. if I am importing `global_imports` from within `b.filereader`, is there a way that the import would know it is specifically `filereader` that is importing it?

---

In the case that the above is doable, would I have ended up polluting the global namespace in other parts of application `b` with both `global_imports.params_a` and `global_imports.params_b`?

If so, is there a better approach to this whole problem? I am seeking for as much transferability of `global_imports` between applications as possible.

---

One foreseeable solution would be to define a function within `global_imports.__init__` through which the use case would be to first import `global_imports` and then call it's function. But this isn't favorable as there is a lot of legacy code to change

Comment: Is there any reason why your application does not explicitly import the params it wants? We can probably help fix this problem, and perhaps the next, but at some point this scheme will fail — what happens when the module is imported by both a.filereader and b.filereader? What happens if params_a and params_b define the same setting?

Comment: It's more of a legacy issue, the developement started from having seperate parameters and functions files, but were eventual bundled as a package. Soon each application had their own package, which became a hassle to update when improvements were made in one of them, so I used `git` and turned it into a submodule

Comment: what do you mean by 'the module'? If you are referring to `global_imports`, that is the main problem I am trying to overcome right now..

Comment: This whole `global_imports` thing seems like a bad idea. That said, you could make things slightly less bad by having the non-common part import the common part instead of the other way around, and having other modules import the specific non-common module they need. That avoids some of the issues you're having.

Comment: Nice suggestion, that way I can do without the function!